# Can an ALTER TABLE accept query results in Access 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am getting a syntax error on the below code trying to execute an ALTER TABLE query in Access 2010. The ulimate goal was to execute this from a VB.net app. Both queries work indepently within Access.

```
ALTER TABLE [Test_table] DROP CONSTRAINT (SELECT [MSysRelationships].[szRelationship]FROM [MSysRelationships] WHERE MSysRelationships.[szObject]='Test_table');
```

I guess the issue is whether or not the ALTER statement can accept query results as the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite sure that Access SQL does not support the syntax you tried to use. You'll probably have to run the SELECT query first, pull the constraint names into a recordset (or similar), then loop through the rows and issue the ALTER TABLE statements one by one.